# dbeaver and other connections somehow consumes postgresql server memory

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I am mostly using DBeaver and psycopg2 and sqlalchemy to connect to my postgresql timescaleDB instance. As I run more and more query, when i perform htop. I realized postgresql is occupying more and more memory.... Is there a way for me to release this memory? Thanks[image]

Edit:
my 2nd replication of the problem.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hANEh.png

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are you actually seeing?  Are you aware that htop does not prorate shared memory, but reports it as being used by each process that touches it?

Comment: Also, are you releasing connections when you are done with a query or set of queries?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver,  ehm... how do i release the connection in dbeaver, psycopg2 and sqlalchemy. Do they have different syntax?

Comment: @jjanes, after i open htop on my ubuntu, I saw a Command called "postgres: postgres postgres 108.32.12.32(61132) idle" eating up 1506MB RES SHR1484MB.... (because currently I only used DBeaver connecting to it....) Last time it was like 10GB RES....

Comment: @jjanes, I attached what did I see... Thanks!

Comment: In psycopg2/sqlalchemy  you call  `close()` on the connection or open the connection in a context manager e.g. `with`. Not sure how you do that in dBeaver. It is a matter of searching the docs.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, I see! Thanks so much! I will try next time when i encounter this problem again!

Comment: @jjanes , I replicated the issue... seems memory is occupy even if i disconnect all of my DBeaver, psycopg, sqlalchemy instance

Comment: @AdrianKlaver  I replicated the issue... seems memory is occupy even if i disconnect all of my DBeaver, psycopg, sqlalchemy instance

Comment: Right, I still don't see any indication of a problem.  The amount of memory used in total (16.3 GB from the Mem line) is only slightly greater than what I assume is your shared memory setting (around 15.4 GB from the VIRT column).

Comment: i see~~ thanks so much! somehow the memory could not be released... even if i disconnect eveything..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the VIRT column, it looks like your shared_buffers is set to 15GB.  That is a curiously large setting to be used by someone concerned about memory usage.

Other than that, there is no indication of a problem here.  None of them is using anywhere near the memory you have given them permission to use; and most of that is shared between them. Meaning you should only count it once, not once per process.

Comment: ehm... from one of my previous experience, it indeed eats up up to 20GB memory... I didn't have the screenshot for now...

Comment: A single process with 20GB under the RES column?  That might be worth looking into if it happens again.  The full process title (like what you censored in the current image) could be very helpful, and the data from pg_stat_activity for that pid, and if you can the details gathered like this: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Developer_FAQ#Examining_backend_memory_use.  When v14 is released, there will also be pg_log_backend_memory_contexts()

Comment: i see~ thanks. the information i hide out is my ip address :D I will update again if the appear again next time.